# web.config transformations in a "WCF service" website

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2010, web-config, web-config-transform

In [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/MIX/MIX10/FT14) Scott Hanselman shows how you can apply transformations to the web config so that you can have different configuration details for development and deployment.

This doesn't seem to be an option in my "WCF service" project though.

Is this posssible? If so how? Otherwise what are the alternatives?

Comment: The MS XSLT Tranform is applicable to website projects and does it during the build. If you want the similar feature you can install a extension called slow cheetah. Check this link : http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SlowCheetahWebconfigTransformationSyntaxNowGeneralizedForAnyXMLConfigurationFile.aspx

Comment: Rajesh is right, a WCF Service Library project will not support web.config transforms but either a WCF web site project or a WCF Service Application project do support web.config transforms.

Comment: You may have noticed that your service library project has no web.config.

Comment: When is used publish on WCF Service Library (with configured slow cheetah extension) it create a build output with nameOfService.dll.config which is correct transformed but the web.config which is created is not transformed. Is there any possibility to get also web.config transformed?